# MySQL was shut down during Index - How to fix the index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, shutdown

MySQL was shut down in the middle of an indexing operation. 
It still works but some of the queries seem much slower than before.
Is there anything particular we can check?
Is it possible that an index gets half way through?

Thanks much

Comment: Have you tried a REPAIR on the relevant table(s)? Failing that, you could dump, cull and re-import the whole database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggested in my comment, you could try a repair on the relevant table(s).

That said, there's a section of the MySQL manual [dedicated to this precise topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html), which details how to use the `REPAIR <table>` statement and indeed dump/re-import.

Is this doesn't make any difference, you may need to check the database settings (if it's a InnoDB engined table/database, it'll *love* being able to be resident in memory for example) and perhaps try to see what specific indexes are being used via an `EXPLAIN` on the queries that are causing pain.

There are also commercial tools such as [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) that'll show what specific queries are being sluggish in quite a lot of detail as well as monitoring other aspects of your system, which may be worth exploring if this is a commercial project/web site.

Comment: Thanks middapark. The DB is pretty big. We looked at a few tables and they seem to be ok. Explain is good suggesting indexes but not telling if an existing index is incomplete. We use the slowquery log and see what we know without knowing if the DB has a "dent". I'll check the reference you are providing. Thanks much though.